# dbt env macro produces wrong output

Tags: dbt

i've encountered strange problem with env var.
Here's my profiles.yml file

```
 project:
  outputs:
    prod:
      type: postgres
      threads: 4
      host: my_host
      port: 5432
      user: "{{ env_var('DBT_USER') }}"
      pass: "{{ env_var('DBT_PASS') }}"
      dbname: my_db
      schema: my_schema

  target: prod
```

Here's my env variables:

```
echo $DBT_USER;
my_user

echo $DBT_PASS;
my_password
```

dbt-debug output:

```
connection to server at "my_host", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_user"
```

But if I change

```
pass: "{{ env_var('DBT_PASS') }}"
```

to

```
my_password
```

in profiles.yml, dbt-debug shows no error.

dbt  version is 1.0.1.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: weird! what database are you using?

Comment: @AndersSwanson profile & port both indicate postgres.

Comment: Does your actual password contain special characters?

Answer (score 0):

@dcpt The way you used the `env_var` function looks correct per the [env_var](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/env_var) docs but there's two things I can think of.

1. Are you restarting your shell after setting your env variables? Maybe there's something about the CLI session that needs to be renewed after a `profiles.yml` or `env_var` change.
2. I think that you need to layout your profiles.yml with target as a higher header? Looking at the example here on [profiles.yml](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/profiles.yml) it looks like:

`profiles.yml`

```
<profile-name>:
  target: <target-name>
  outputs:
    <target-name>:
      type: <bigquery | postgres | redshift | snowflake | other>
      schema: <schema_identifier>
      threads: <natural_number>
```

But you have your `target:` at the bottom? Is that supposed to be an additional target definition or should it be higher above your `prod:` tag.